# MS Office does not start with NVIDIA card

Tags: microsoft-excel, drivers, microsoft-office, nvidia-quadro, discrete-graphics

When I try and start any Microsoft Office product from the discrete graphics card (rather than the integrated card), the program (Excel, Word, etc) crashes immediately rather than starting up. The problem does not occur when using the integrated graphics card, but I need it to work since I have to be able to call Excel from a graphics-intensive application.

I'm working on a Lenovo W520, which has an NVIDIA Quadro 1000M discrete graphics card, currently running the 362.77 driver. I'm using Office 2016 (Office 365 ProPlus).  **How can I make MS Office applications work from my NVIDIA Quadro 1000M?**

I have tried the 342.01, 355.85, 362.56 and 362.77 drivers from NVIDIA, of which only 342.01 worked (but this driver left WhatsApp desktop and Google Chrome pitch black, of which I could only fix the latter). *If you have a different driver compatible with the Quadro 1000M and cannot reproduce the problem, please share this as well so I can try this.*

I included a representative crash log from AppCrashView below.

```
Version=1
EventType=APPCRASH
EventTime=131514951888029313
ReportType=2
Consent=1
UploadTime=131514951892050582
ReportStatus=268435456
ReportIdentifier=171aca5b-2229-4107-82f9-5f957f2754bf
IntegratorReportIdentifier=5e27116f-0af3-4160-a499-d434a70d5694
Wow64Host=34404
AppSessionGuid=000031a8-0001-001a-0f69-8fe5263cd301
TargetAppId=W:0006bef06d462af48581c2c5598bb1892efa00000000!0000a17d2a423ce3a4ba302c8530e26041d9da30ebd9!EXCEL.EXE
TargetAppVer=2017//09//08:06:25:11!2981fb3!EXCEL.EXE
BootId=4294967295
TargetAsId=347
Response.BucketId=04f106cd8efcedae7b136718e24bf22d
Response.BucketTable=4
Response.LegacyBucketId=120839754736
Response.type=4
Sig[0].Name=Application Name
Sig[0].Value=EXCEL.EXE
Sig[1].Name=Application Version
Sig[1].Value=16.0.8201.2193
Sig[2].Name=Application Timestamp
Sig[2].Value=59b237c7
Sig[3].Name=Fault Module Name
Sig[3].Value=mso20win32client.dll
Sig[4].Name=Fault Module Version
Sig[4].Value=0.0.0.0
Sig[5].Name=Fault Module Timestamp
Sig[5].Value=59b25fff
Sig[6].Name=Exception Code
Sig[6].Value=010e0511
Sig[7].Name=Exception Offset
Sig[7].Value=00000000001b64d3
DynamicSig[1].Name=OS Version
DynamicSig[1].Value=10.0.15063.2.0.0.768.101
DynamicSig[2].Name=Locale ID
DynamicSig[2].Value=1043
UI[2]=C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Root\Office16\EXCEL.EXE
UI[3]=Microsoft Excel has stopped working
UI[4]=Windows can check online for a solution to the problem.
UI[5]=Check online for a solution and close the program
UI[6]=Check online for a solution later and close the program
UI[7]=Close the program
LoadedModule[0]=C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Root\Office16\EXCEL.EXE
LoadedModule[1]=C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
LoadedModule[2]=C:\WINDOWS\System32\KERNEL32.DLL
LoadedModule[3]=C:\WINDOWS\System32\KERNELBASE.dll
LoadedModule[4]=C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\apphelp.dll
LoadedModule[5]=C:\WINDOWS\System32\ucrtbase.dll
LoadedModule[6]=C:\WINDOWS\System32\ADVAPI32.dll
LoadedModule[7]=C:\WINDOWS\System32\msvcrt.dll
LoadedModule[8]=C:\WINDOWS\System32\sechost.dll
LoadedModule[9]=C:\WINDOWS\System32\RPCRT4.dll
LoadedModule[10]=C:\WINDOWS\System32\ole32.dll
LoadedModule[11]=C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\VCRUNTIME140.dll
LoadedModule[12]=C:\WINDOWS\System32\combase.dll
LoadedModule[13]=C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\MSVCP140.dll
LoadedModule[14]=C:\WINDOWS\System32\bcryptPrimitives.dll
LoadedModule[15]=C:\WINDOWS\System32\GDI32.dll
LoadedModule[16]=C:\WINDOWS\System32\gdi32full.dll
LoadedModule[17]=C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Root\Office16\AppVIsvSubsystems64.dll
LoadedModule[18]=C:\WINDOWS\System32\msvcp_win.dll
LoadedModule[19]=C:\WINDOWS\System32\USER32.dll
LoadedModule[20]=C:\WINDOWS\System32\win32u.dll
LoadedModule[21]=C:\WINDOWS\System32\SHELL32.dll
LoadedModule[22]=C:\WINDOWS\System32\cfgmgr32.dll
LoadedModule[23]=C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Root\Office16\oart.dll
LoadedModule[24]=C:\WINDOWS\System32\shcore.dll
LoadedModule[25]=C:\WINDOWS\System32\windows.storage.dll
LoadedModule[26]=C:\WINDOWS\System32\shlwapi.dll
LoadedModule[27]=C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Root\Office16\AppVIsvStream64.dll
LoadedModule[28]=C:\WINDOWS\System32\kernel.appcore.dll
LoadedModule[29]=C:\WINDOWS\System32\powrprof.dll
LoadedModule[30]=C:\WINDOWS\System32\profapi.dll
LoadedModule[31]=C:\WINDOWS\WinSxS\amd64_microsoft.windows.common-controls_6595b64144ccf1df_6.0.15063.483_none_26002d27e7c744a2\COMCTL32.dll
LoadedModule[32]=C:\WINDOWS\WinSxS\amd64_microsoft.windows.gdiplus_6595b64144ccf1df_1.1.15063.608_none_56f0266b425534e9\gdiplus.dll
LoadedModule[33]=C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\USERENV.dll
LoadedModule[34]=C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Root\Office16\c2r64.dll
LoadedModule[35]=C:\WINDOWS\System32\OLEAUT32.dll
LoadedModule[36]=C:\WINDOWS\System32\IMM32.DLL
LoadedModule[37]=C:\Windows\system32\nvinitx.dll
LoadedModule[38]=C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\VERSION.dll
LoadedModule[39]=C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\CoProcManager\_etoured.dll
LoadedModule[40]=C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\CoProcManager\nvd3d9wrapx.dll
LoadedModule[41]=C:\WINDOWS\System32\SETUPAPI.dll
LoadedModule[42]=C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\CoProcManager\nvdxgiwrapx.dll
LoadedModule[43]=C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Office16\mso20win32client.dll
LoadedModule[44]=C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Office16\mso30win32client.dll
LoadedModule[45]=C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Office16\mso40uiwin32client.dll
LoadedModule[46]=C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Office16\mso50win32client.dll
LoadedModule[47]=C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Office16\mso98win32client.dll
LoadedModule[48]=C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\WTSAPI32.dll
LoadedModule[49]=C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Office16\mso99Lwin32client.dll
LoadedModule[50]=C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\MSIMG32.dll
LoadedModule[51]=C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Office16\mso.dll
LoadedModule[52]=C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\msi.dll
LoadedModule[53]=C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\bcrypt.dll
LoadedModule[54]=C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\d2d1.dll
LoadedModule[55]=C:\WINDOWS\System32\CRYPT32.dll
LoadedModule[56]=C:\WINDOWS\System32\MSASN1.dll
LoadedModule[57]=C:\WINDOWS\system32\uxtheme.dll
LoadedModule[58]=C:\WINDOWS\System32\MSCTF.dll
LoadedModule[59]=C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\WINSTA.dll
LoadedModule[60]=C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\dxgi.dll
LoadedModule[61]=C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\DEVOBJ.dll
LoadedModule[62]=C:\WINDOWS\System32\WINTRUST.dll
LoadedModule[63]=C:\WINDOWS\system32\dwmapi.dll
LoadedModule[64]=C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\d3d10_1.dll
LoadedModule[65]=C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\d3d10_1core.dll
LoadedModule[66]=C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\d3d11.dll
LoadedModule[67]=C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\nvumdshimx.dll
LoadedModule[68]=C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\Secur32.dll
LoadedModule[69]=C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\SSPICLI.DLL
LoadedModule[70]=C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\mscoree.dll
LoadedModule[71]=C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\mscoreei.dll
LoadedModule[72]=C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\DWrite.dll
State[0].Key=Transport.DoneStage1
State[0].Value=1
FriendlyEventName=Stopped working
ConsentKey=APPCRASH
AppName=Microsoft Excel
AppPath=C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\EXCEL.EXE
ApplicationIdentity=00000000000000000000000000000000
MetadataHash=-992592777
```

I already tried [this Microsoft Support guide](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3160013/office-applications-crash-or-cannot-start), but the registry key `ShownFirstRunOptin` already had `1` as a value. The problem also persists if I disable McAfee Access Protection, On-Delivery Email Scanner as well as On-Access Scanner.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried turning on hardware acceleration?

Start any Office program, on the File tab, click Options. In the Options dialog box, click Advanced. In the list of available options, click to select the Disable hardware graphics acceleration check box. Click OK.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Sadly, it did not provide a solution to my problem.

Comment: It should have because you indicate the problem does not happen if you use the iGPU.  Honestly it sounds like the Office doesn't support hardware acceleration with the Quadro 1000M which isn't shocking honestly.

Comment: Another thought, have you tried running any of the programs in safe mode. If you open the run command type "Excel.exe /safe" to get launch it in safe mode. Maybe there is some odd plugin causing this.

Comment: One additional thought, in the Nvidia control panel, under Manage 3D settings, select program settings. From there, manually add Excel and then you can specify the preferred graphics processor, which will allow you select the integrated graphics card.